# Projection with subquery for Property in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have a performance problem in projections of Entity Framework.

My find has a projection with a list of sub-property:

```
public List<UserProjection> FindUserAndLastOrder(List<Guid> idsUser)
{
    return _entity.Where(x => idsUser.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => new UserProjection()
    {
        Email = x.Email,
        LastOrderId = x.Orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.CreatedAt).First().Id,
        Price = x.Orders.OrderByDescending(order=> order.CreatedAt).First().Price
    }).ToList();
}
```

Then run the query and it executes two subqueries: one for getting order id and the other for getting price

Has a solution for saving subquery in variable and reusing value in two points?

entities examples:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Email { get; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Key { get; private set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set;}
}

public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Guid IdUser { get; set; }
}

public class UserProjection
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid LastOrderId { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to use a double projection, one to get the relevant data, and the second in memory to compose your desired model:

```
return _entity
    .Where(x => idsUser.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Email,
        LastOrder = x.Orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.CreatedAt)
            .Select(o => new 
            { 
                o.Id,
                o.Price
            }).First()
    }).Select(x => new UserProjection
    {
        Email = x.Email,
        LastOrderId = x.LastOrder.Id,
        Price = x.LastOrder.Price
    }).ToList();
```

You *might* need to materialize the first step /w a `ToList()` after the first `Select` if EF complains, but that wouldn't really have much impact on performance, just a bit of memory use for the double-projection. (depending on how many users you are retrieving)

Note: This assumes that every user has at least one order which may be a problem if there are users without orders. In which case you'd likely want to use a `FirstOrDefault` then handle that the "LastOrder" detail might be #null and ensure LastOrderId and Price are nullable.